# How to get results of sonar ant task and published them on Jenkins?

Tags: ant, jenkins, sonarqube

I prepare ant task for sonar and it works(i see results on sonar page and build is successful). But how to show results of analize in jenkins? I see no results in my workdir.

```
<target name="sonar" depends="depended targets">
    <!-- Execute Sonar -->
    <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
    <sonar:sonar key="key" version="1.0" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">
        <sources>
            <path location="someSrcDir1" />
            <path location="someSrcDir2" />
            <path location="someSrcDir3" />
        </sources>

         <binaries>
            <path location="someDirWithBin1" />
            <path location="someDirWithBin1" />
            <path location="someDirWithBin1" />
            <path location="someDirWithBin1" />
         </binaries>    
    </sonar:sonar>
</target>
```

How to get and publish results in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to publish Sonar results into Jenkins, those are 2 different products used for different purposes. After a Sonar analysis has been executed by a Jenkins job, you have to go to the Sonar Web interface to get the results.

The only thing you can get is a link from Jenkins to Sonar, but it is only available when using Maven or the Sonar standalone build step (and what's more, it is a bit buggy).

Comment: Sow i can`t generate link to results from ant task??